# When import snapshot data :internal error, uncaught exception: Out of memory

Tags: node

tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full.tar.lz4 --data-dir=/mnt/abc

Aug  1 03:56:17 - shell.snapshots: Importing data from snapshot file mainnet.full.tar.lz4

Aug  1 03:56:17 - shell.snapshots: You may consider using the --block  argument to verify that the block imported is the one you expect

Aug  1 03:56:17 - shell.snapshots: Retrieving and validating data. This can take a while, please bear with us

Aug  1 03:56:18 - node.main: Cleaning directory /mnt/abc because of failure
tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:

```
        Out of memory

        Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29

        Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18

        Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26

        Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24

        Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 25, characters 27-34

        Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 116, characters 32-39
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: where you got that snapshot from? if that worked for you , please let me know the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors appears when your machine is running out of RAM while importing a snapshot. A snasphot import can be done with around 2GB of RAM (event less I think). Does your machine meet the requirements ?

However, it seems that the command your are executing (`tezos-node snapshot import mainnet.full.tar.lz4 --data-dir=/mnt/abc`) is using a compressed snasphot file: `mainnet.full.tar.lz4`.
Should not you extract it first using `lz4 -d mainnet.full.tar.lz4 | tar xf -` ?

Comment: Thanks your reply. My mistake lz4 -d mainnet.full.tar.lz4 | tar xf - is right.